# Modally present UIImagePickerController does not hide UITabBar if current view has UINavigationController as container controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, hidden

I have a tabbar app and the second tab goes to a navigation controller-style view.

on the rightButton of the navigation bar I have a camera icon to present modally the ImagePicker. However it will not become fullscreen but instead underlay the tabbar.

The first image show that I have a navigation controller container this first rootView which has a camera button. When click it will just create a UIImagePickerController and present it modally. Nothing special.

[first http://www.jobline.com.sg/images/no_use/1.png](http://www.jobline.com.sg/images/no_use/1.png)

However the result of the camera is missing the control to take/cancel picture like this:

[second http://www.jobline.com.sg/images/no_use/2.png](http://www.jobline.com.sg/images/no_use/2.png)

How do I hide the UITabBar and able to see the camera control? I know it can be done because the Skype profile tab also have a camera and then present a UIActionSheet to "Take picture" and then the full-screen camera view. I believe the profile tab has navigation controller as its root view also.

Thanks a million for your help.

Here is the code that I used:

```
- (void)takePicture:(id)sender {
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  } else {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  }

  [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

It is a fairly straightforward code of presenting an imagePicker modally. So I wonder why there is no camera control and how come my tabbar can overlap it. Is it because of my view hierarchy?

Comment: How are you presenting it? Can you add the code?

Comment: Hi Deepak, code added :)

Comment: Looks like it should work as is. I have this in a [`sample code`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/CamTab.zip) and it seems to work fine. Can you tell me what've you done differently so that I can reproduce the error?

Comment: Thank you Deepak. You are so helpful! However I am doing some of my view programmatically. Here is [my code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6815194/CameraDemo.zip) 

Btw.. self is ClaimController which is the root view controller for the UINavigationController :)

Comment: Okay.. I think I found the cause. I am having a totally new class just to house the UINavigationController instead of doing it directly at the AppDelegate :(

Sorry.. is my lack of view controller understanding hehe...

I now do this

`ClaimController *claimController = [[ClaimController alloc] init];`
`UINavigationController *claimNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:claimController];`

at the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: And is it working? I just downloaded the code so let me know if I don't need to look into it further?

Comment: Thanks Deepak for the help which leads me to re-look his sample code and found the cause. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i have a solution, but it is somewhat "hacky." My idea is to post a notification to NSNotificationCenter that calls a method which hides the tabbar. An example:

Inside the application delegate (or whatever controls your tabbar...)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideTabbar) name:@"hideTab" object:nil];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)hideTabbar{
    [[_tabBarController tabBar] setHidden:YES];
}
```

And then to hide the tab bar when the camera view appears just post the notification, like so

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideTab" object:nil];
```

And then of course have one to unhide it when the camera view goes away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for this info. Yes you have help me successfully hide the tabbar, but the camera control is nowhere to be seen :(

I actually need to have the camera control appearing also.

Comment: Definitely hacky as you said... but I couldn't find any way less hacky !  Thanks!  I didn't bother with sending a notification though.  I just called [self.navigationViewController.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES] when presenting the camera, and then setHidden:NO when dismissing the camera.